# Minicom offline when trying to communicate using USB to RS232 cable

Tags: linux, serial-port, usbserial

I'm using a USB to RS232 cable to communicate between two linux machines. On the machine with the USB side connected, I run:

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

And get the following output:

```
console [tty0] enabled
serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
00:0a: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
00:0b: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
usb 2-1.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

So far so good. Now I run a `minicom -s` and using "Serial port setup", I change "Serial Device" to be "/dev/ttyUSB0", "BPS/Par/Bits" to be "115200 8N1", and select "No" for "Hardware Flow Control" and "Software Flow Control".

I save these settings as default, exit from minicom, and then run `minicom` again.

Minicom opens, however it remains "offline". I can't enter any commands. The other Linux machine connected to the Serial port side of the wire is on and running fine. Why can't I connect to this other Linux machine?

Comment: wow I'm have the same problem with the same USB-SERIAL adapter

Answer (score 0):

Minicom decides offline/online based on whether DCD line is connected or not. I created a null modem cable and tested that data is transferred as it should however minicom shows offline. Browsing through the code I found that it checks for DCD line connection to set a variable for online.

This library I used for testing in java serial port https://github.com/RishiGupta12/serial-communication-manager